# SP2013 App icon not rendered, only App link is displayed + how we can set the sliding transparent hover text over App icon?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-clientobject

I am facing an App Icon related issue. I am creating SharePoint Hosted App which I am deploying to SP 2013 Developer site.

By default any app will have the AppIcon set under Images folder. Also it is referred in AppManifest.xml.

I am able to deploy my app successfully and it works fine, **but I don’t see the icon/image for the App. All I see is a link of the name of the app.**

I have tried another image/Another App, but every time I see the link only.

Any one have any idea on that??

Also curious to know **how we can set the sliding transparent hover text over App icon??**

Comment: I have got the icon displaying for app. Actually in Sp2013 developer site, **by design** you will see link only after app deployment. But once you see the site content location, you will be able to see the recently installed App with proper Icon.

Still looking for answer on:    
**how we can set the sliding transparent hover text over App icon??**

Comment: Why is this by design? Isn't the icon a good piece of feedback to the users to distinguish one app from another? I think the icon should be shown at all times.